# How to use .NET TextBoxRenderer with TextBoxState.Hot to draw a hot text box?

Tags: winforms, visual-styles

i am trying to use [`TextBoxRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxrenderer.aspx) to render a "hot" text box:

```
TextBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(e.Graphics, rectangle, TextBoxState.Hot);
```

except that it doesn't work, it doesn't render the text box as hot.

- `TextBoxState.Selected` doesn't render as selected
- `TextBoxState.Hot` doesn't render as hot

[image]

How do i make `TextBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(..., Hot)` render as `Hot`?

### Related but different question:

How do i make `TextBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(..., Selected)` render as `Selected`?

Comment: I hate to keep ruining your day, but the MSDN article states: "Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform Note: Visual styles are supported only on these platforms."

Comment: @LarsTech That's a a documentation issue. They're probably trying to say that visual styles are unsupported on Windows XP Starter Edition (which doesn't support themes). They could have phrased it conceptually better, saying, "VisualStyleRenderer is unsupported on operating systems that don't support visual styles." If you want to hold the documentation literally true, then the Task Scheduler API is unsupported on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `TextBoxRenderer` uses `EP_BACKGROUNDWITHBORDER`, whereas `EP_EDITBORDER_NOSCROLL` is typically used by `TextBox` controls[[1]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/46e66852-b52e-420d-8fe0-b717f86ecb18).

```
if (VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported)
{
  // Use the text control's focus rectangle.
  // EP_EDITBORDER_NOSCROLL, EPSN_FOCUSED
  VisualStyleElement element = VisualStyleElement.CreateElement("EDIT", 6, 3);
  if (VisualStyleRenderer.IsElementDefined(element))
  {
    VisualStyleRenderer renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(element);
    renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle);
  }
}
```

(It's tempting to try to get the element from `VisualStyleElement` but there's no nested class for `EP_EDITBORDER_NOSCROLL`. So numeric constants 6 and 3 it is.)

Comment: This should work as provided, however .NET's UxTheme wrapper couldn't validate that specific part/state combination. I had success getting my project to work with [this solution on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18603/Advanced-UxTheme-wrapper).